# how to debug source code from Google code repository

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, netbeans

I want to debug the following source code from google code repository,

```
http://code.google.com/p/rx/
```

My problem is, I am unable to find a suitable ide which can consider all the sub-folders in the source code as one complete project. I have tried netbeans C++, codeblocks, eclipse C++,etc. The problem with all of them while opening the project is that they consider all the subfolders within the main project as different projects.

Is there any ide which can be used for debugging the source code from google code repository. OR IS THERE ANY WAY OF DEBUGGING THESE PROJECTS?

Operating System: Ubuntu or Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dummy makefile :

```
all:
        g++ code_dir/*/*.?pp -o fake
```

and then import project using Makefiles. This is possible to do for kdevelop and eclipse (not sure for other IDEs).

Take a note that the above makefile imports all files with a `*.?pp` template from all directories in the code_dir directory.

Comment: If make files are already present. As in this case, is it possible to import the project using those make files, if yes then how?

Comment: @user869790 Doesn't matter if makefiles exist or not. You can always create a dummy makefile that is going to touch all files in target directories. In that case, you'll have to set IDE's build system

Comment: When I am using the above command i.e. g++ code_dir/* -0 fake its returning to me that the subfolder file formats are not recognised. That means I have to create a make file for all the sub-folders.....now when I am putting in the name of the sub-folders instead of the code_dir...i am getting the same error for the files...is this the right approach. In case I am wrong..then please do correct me.

Comment: @user869790 Modified the post a bit. Just copy and paste this into a dummy makefile. `code_dir` is the directory containing subfolders with source/header files (change it accordingly however the project is organized). Also `-O` is wrong parameter for g++ (it is `-o`)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new project with your favorite IDE and then import the sources manually.

You might also consider using a decent editor. Personally, I prefer vim and don't see any appealing reason to use an editor 10 times the size of the actual project.

Comment: In this case..do we have to create make-files also inside the new project.

Comment: If your IDE is not able to create a simple makefile by itself, you can easily come up with your own makefile. See VJovic's answer and its comments.