# How to debug an existing project in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, netbeans, kdevelop

I want to debug an existing project "http://www.gnu.org/software/rx/rx.html" in eclipse..i followed through the article

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-eclipse/index.html

Whenever I try to run the build.xml ant file...it tells me

> "make: unix/Makefile: No such file or directory"

Also I tried to follow the approach in :

[how to debug source code from Google code repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497636/how-to-debug-source-code-from-google-code-repository)

However, even the approach suggested by VJovic does not work in my case. I also downloaded the code still the approach suggested by VJovic does not work in that case too. I have been stuck at it for more than 100 hours..someone please help. I am a novice in this...please excuse my ignorance.

I am open to ide suggestion. The operating systems that I like working in are Ubuntu and Windows 7. Also I tried KDevelop...it is able to build my project...but throws an error with header files as it is not able to find them.

Comment: @VJovic Sorry for disturbing..but since u replied to some other question. Can u please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

may be this links will be helpful for you.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_debug_exes.htm

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/debug/index.php

Comment: Thanks a ton for replying..I tried them to..but does not seem to work for me..my bad luck :( I tried for gnu: rx and rdf-3x both...does not work...Again thanks a lot for being so helpful. Also it will debug an existing executable..whereas I want to debug an existing source code.